# Variável retorna caracteres estranhos

Tags: php, mysql, variáveis

Estou utilizando o CPU-Z que ao escanear o seu pc ele você tem a opção de salvar o log em txt ou html para que possa ser visto manualmente. Feito isso exportei para html e executei

```
INSERT INTO `root`.`mycomputers`(id, token, html) VALUES (NULL, '08dade78-6f3c-401b-899f-aa7035d001fb', 'CODIGO_HTML_DO_LOG_DO_CPU-Z');
```

> Onde o **id** é A_I (AutoIncrement)

Fiz o esquema abaixo para com que o html seja exibido toda vez que eu fornecer o token correto, mas após a consulta o resultado retorna um caractere desconhecido = �

```php
<?php
    $token = $_GET["token"];
    $html = "";
    $title = "";

    header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw");
    mysql_select_db("root");

    $cmd_q = "SELECT * FROM `mycomputer` WHERE token='$token'";
    $cmd_r = mysql_query($cmd_q);

    $cmd_s = mysql_fetch_row($cmd_r);
    $html = $cmd_s[2];
    $title = $cmd_s[3];
?>

<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.cpuid.com/medias/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">document.title="<?php echo $title; ?>"</script> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<?php echo $html; ?>
```

Em determinados caracteres como o símbolo que junto ao => **°** C que representa Graus Celsius. O Html dentro da database retorna no lugar do `°` isso `Temperature 0   32�C (89�F) [0x35] (Core #0)`

> OBS: Na base de dados o símbolo ° se apresenta normalmente, mas no html fica desta maneira!

Outras linha que ocorrem o mesmo:

```
     Temperature 0   38�C (100�F) [0x26] (TMPIN0)
        Temperature 1   35�C (95�F) [0x23] (TMPIN1)
        Temperature 2   32�C (89�F) [0x20] (TMPIN2)
        Fan 0   2742 RPM [0x223] (FANIN0)
        Fan 2   2836 RPM [0x211] (FANIN2)
        Fan PWM 0   63 pc [0xA0] (CPU)
        Fan PWM 1   60 pc [0x99] (System Fan 1)
        Fan PWM 2   60 pc [0x99] (System Fan 2)
        Fan PWM 3   60 pc [0x99] (System Fan 3)

Hardware monitor    NVIDIA NVAPI
        Temperature 0   45�C (113�F) [0x2D] (TMPIN0)
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xewkjte/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta com problema no padrão de codificação de caracteres, tente usar no seu html head:
troque:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

para:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

Comment: Funcionou! Mas ainda não entendi, a diferença entre as duas.